# Comparing a user entered value to that stored in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Currently I have a file reader that reads in the data from a file line by line and will check to make sure that they are entered in the format required and if they are then it will add them to the array and add output them to the console. What I want to do is make it so that the user can enter a specific team and it will go through the file and only record the relevant data to that team but I'm not sure how I would do this. Here is the code I have that will record and print the data from the text file:

```
String hteam;
    String ateam;
    int hscore;
    int ascore;
    int totgoals = 0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(fileName))).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*");



    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        String[] words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");
        //splits the file at colons

        if(verifyFormat(words)) {
            hteam = words[0];       // read the home team
            ateam = words[1];       // read the away team
            hscore = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);       //read the home team score
            totgoals = totgoals + hscore;
            ascore = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);       //read the away team score
            totgoals = totgoals + ascore;
            validresults = validresults + 1;
```

My question is how would i make it so that the user can enter a team name then it will compare that to the names for either hteam or ateam and carry on reading each line of the loop.

Comment: So you wan't to be able to enter a team name, and then compare what?

Comment: @hoyah_hayoh the users will enter a team name & in the text file that is being read into the system it has team names on each line so it will check if either of those names match. If it does then it will increment a certain number to mark how many times it has matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're interested in counting the amount of matches of a team in your file I'd use a `Map`. First, populate the map:

```
Map<String, Integer> teams = new HashMap<>();

String team = "team A";
if(teams.containsKey(team)) {
    teams.put(team, teams.get(team) + 1);
} else {
    teams.put(team, 1);
}
```

Then, retrieve the amount of matches:

```
String userTeam = "...";
if(teams.containsKey(userTeam)) {
    System.out.println(userTeam + ": " + teams.get(userTeam));
} else {
    System.out.println(userTeam + " unknown");
}
```

Comment: If we understood the question correct this is the way to go. Good thing to not define it as a `HashMap<K,V>` but instead as a `Map<K,V>`.

Comment: Ah, I see this makes sense rather than the way I was trying thanks.